# using ar how to I add to libfoo.a bar.o and call result libnew.a

Tags: ar

Is there a way using ar to add to existing libfoo.a library an additional object bar.o and specify the name of the result libnew.a?

Comment: doesn't `man ar` tell you that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can achieve the goal by just copying and renaming the .a and the using 'ar -cr'. It just felt like ar might be able to do this in one command